# Adding products causes "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in Gd2.php on line 184"

Tags: magento2, products, magento-2.0

I am attempting to add products to Magento 2.0 but every time I go and add one it gives me the following error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/admin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 184

Can anyone help? Here is the code I am using:

[image]

Comment: Did you resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't applicable to your exact issue, the following topic shows how to increase the PHP `max_execution_time` which hopefully will fix your issue.

[http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_70pct.html](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_70pct.html